# Draw Double Headed Arrow in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to draw a double headed arrow as a plot in pgfplots but the arrow does not seem to be rendering right. Below a minimal example of an attempt to draw a double sided arrow with pgfplots (red line), as can be seen in the plot the leftmost arrow is pointing the wrong way.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax = 10, ymax = 10, legend pos = south east] 
    \addplot [<->, red, thick] (0,0) to (9,9);
    \draw[<->, blue, thick] (0,1) to (8, 9);

    \addlegendentry{plot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anyone provide any insights on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to use `pgfplots` when to do this `TikZ` is enough?

Comment: @AndréC perhaps just the principal of it? I'd say it is a legitimate question. It you can reduce it to `<-` (which presumably is the part being used in `<->`). Using `pgfplots` is often a fast too to get the axis even if the plot is just done by hand.

Comment: `\addplot [<->, red, thick,domain=0:9] {x};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrong defined `addplot`. Try:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
%\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmax = 10, ymax = 10, legend pos = south east]
    \addplot [<->, red, thick] coordinates {(0,0)  (9,9)}; % <----
    \draw[<->, blue, thick] (0,1) to (8, 9);
    \addlegendentry{plot}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Macro `\addplot` is designed for drawing function (on given domain with defined number of sampling points), drawing lines between number of coordinates collected in `table` or in `coordinates`(as it is done in above MWE). Functions can draw with use of the Bezier curves or only draw their coordinates with different marks, etc. It not support drawing lines between two coordinates using `to`, `edge` or `--` as it is at "ordinary" path (draw) commands.

The details should be described in the `pgfplots` manual. For further question about syntax please address them to package author (with new question).

Comment: any explanation as to why the other syntax would not work?

Comment: @daleif The other syntax does not seem to match the required syntax `\addplot[⟨options⟩] ⟨input data⟩ ⟨trailing path commands⟩;` as described on page 43 of the pgfplots manual. So maybe a better question is, why did it not result in an error, but mangled output instead?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I think you're right, I cannot find any information as to ` to ` being a supported syntax for `\addplot`, but since `\addplot` ends up as a `\path`  (I assume), the result is valid for `\path`, that might explain the missing error msg, but not quite the strange output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't realise that the syntax was not valid.